# Why does "a" < "A" return TRUE in R?

Tags: r, lexicographic, lexicographic-ordering

My understanding is that the lexicographic comparison of two characters reflects the numerical comparison of the corresponding Unicode numeric codes of those characters. For example

```
> utf8ToInt("a")
[1] 97
>
>
> utf8ToInt("b")
[1] 98
>
>
> # Because 97 < 98 the following lexicographical comparison returns TRUE
> "a" < "b"
[1] TRUE
>
```

Yet, there is a particular case that I cannot understand and explain:

```
> utf8ToInt("a")
[1] 97
>
>
> utf8ToInt("A")
[1] 65
>
>
> # Because 97 > 65 normally the following lexicographical comparison
> # is supposed to return FALSE, yet to my surprise it returns TRUE!
> "a" < "A"
[1] TRUE
>
```

I checked with `Python 3.10.4`, `DuckDB 0.7.0` and I can confirm that both of them return `FALSE` as the result for the comparison `'a' < 'A'`. However, `PostgreSQL 15.3` like `R`, returns `TRUE`. So I'm really confused by this difference of behaviour.

Why does `R` and `PostgreSQL` return `TRUE` for the comparison `"a" < "A"` ?

Comment: May depend on local settings, e.g. see `?Comparison`

Comment: Thanks for the help. What local should I set with Sys.setlocale to get a coherent result ?

Comment: The answer to "Why does R ... return TRUE for the comparison "a" < "A"" is, it uses the lexicographic order which depends on the locales. Use e.g. `utf8ToInt` to get the C-like ASCII-order behavior, `utf8ToInt("a") < utf8ToInt("A")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not really a notion of a single atomic `char` in R as you get in other languages like C; the closest R has is a length-1 string vector where the single string contains a single character. This means that comparison operators always compare single characters the same as they compare any other strings - that is, lexicographically, not as 8-bit numbers as in C. This lexicographic ordering is locale-dependent, being ascertained by the [`Scollate`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/aa16443f07f54e4e2af66b68e6d29ee736004947/src/main/util.c#L2487) function in the underlying C code, which does so by reading the LC_COLLATE environment variable.

If you want ASCII-based lexicographic ordering, you can set LC_COLLATE to "C":

```r
Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", "C")
```

Then we have:

```r
"a" < "A"
#> [1] FALSE
```

Just be aware that any code you write this way will not be portable. It is more robust to use `utf8ToInt` or similar, and specifically convert to numbers if you want to compare ASCII values in R.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Please correct me if I'm wrong, given that a lexicographic comparison is always based on numeric comparison (numeric codes of the characters) and given that as you mentioned this is locale-dependent, is it correct to say,that depending on the configured locale on the server, a same character (or a string vector of length one in R as you mentioned) may have different numeric codes used during lexicographic comparison, which is not necessarily always equal to numeric codes in ASCII or UTF-8 ? On our server Sys.getlocale() returns LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252

Comment: No, that's not correct.  The same character will always have the same numeric code. The way collation is localized is by comparing those codes in a non-numeric way.  It's also possible to compare multiple character sequences differently than comparing one letter at a time.  I don't think this happens in English language locales, but in Czech, "ch" falls between "h" and "i".

Comment: Yes, lexicographic comparison is _not_ always done according to numeric values. In most locales, the characters are mapped to an alphabet, and it is this alphabet that is used as the lexicographic order, not the numeric value of the character as an ascii entity

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing this out. This means that my understanding of even the definition of "lexicographic comparison" was wrong. At college, during C programming course, the lexicographic comparison was presented to us as ASCII numeric codes mapping to characters which if I understand correctly, switched later towards Unicode numeric codes. I always thought that locales would concern things such as date format, how number with decimal point are printed, etc. but I never thought that they would impact the very concept of lexicographic comparison, and I see now how wrong I have been!